# How to reference proper directory in a github actions workflows to call a module

Tags: github-actions

I'm running my workflows using GitHub Actions. When I create a pull_request that will trigger my workflow, I am getting the error message at the bottom of my question. What I am trying to do is to call my infrastructure/test/main.tf from my audit-account/prod-env directory. What do i need to change in the Env section for directory

```
# deploy.yml

name: 'GitHub OIDC workflow'
on:
  pull_request:
       branches:
         - prod
env:
  tf_version: 'latest'
  tg_version: 'latest'
  tf_working_dir: './audit-account/prod-env'
permissions:
    id-token: write
    contents: read
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: 'Build and Deploy'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: 'checkout'
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          aws-region: us-east-1
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/GitHubActions_Workflow_role
          role-duration-seconds: 3600

      - name: 'Terragrunt Init'
        uses: the-commons-project/terragrunt-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.tf_version }}
          tg_actions_version: ${{ env.tg_version }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'init'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.tf_working_dir }}
          tf_actions_comment: true
        env:
          TF_INPUT: false
```

```
# audit-account/prod-env/terragrunt.hcl

terraform {
  source = "../../../../..//infrastructure/test"
}

include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

infrastructure/test
main.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "test-vpc" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "OIDC"
  }
}
```

error message:

```
init: info: initializing Terragrunt configuration in /audit-account/prod-env
init: error: failed to initialize Terragrunt configuration in /audit-account/prod-env
time=2021-11-17T23:55:54Z level=error msg=Working dir infrastructure/test from source file:///github/workspace/audit-account/prod-env does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source path for the infrastructure module goes way too far up in the folder structure.

Assuming you have the infrastructure and audit-account directories at the root of the repository, your source would be `../../infrastructure/test`. You have it looking 5 folders up from `audit-account/prod-env`, which puts you 3 folders above the workspace in a folder somewhere on the runner's filesystem.